# Use to add retina images using Google-Maps-for-Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, retina-display

I'm using the gem Google-Maps-for-Rails. Everything is working correctly, but it looks terrible on any retina display. Looking at the documentation, I would think there would be some mention on how to do it.

https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Markers#customize-each-marker

But there is nothing here regarding scaling the picture.

I know it's possible. In the google maps api doc, there is a property called scaledSize:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Icon

It's being used in the following examples:

http://robandlauren.com/2013/05/08/responsive-google-maps/
http://samcroft.co.uk/2011/google-maps-marker-icons-for-iphone-retina-display/

But not sure how to set the scaledSize with the gem Google-Maps-for-Rails.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: did you ever sort this one out?

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/issues/380

Comment: Let me know if you have any problems. It's been a while since I looked at this.

Comment: Oh, and I did get it to work: https://bonjourn.al/journal/22-japan/map